# python to generate html color table output

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am planning write HTML table with color using python script.

I got below script in below link and started testing.
[Click here](https://www.decalage.info/python/html)

```
 from html import HTML
 import sys
 import os
 table_data = [
        ['Last name',   'First name',   'Age'],
        ['Smith',       'John',         30],
        ['Carpenter',   'Jack',         47],
        ['Johnson',     'Paul',         62],
    ]
htmlcode = HTML.table(table_data)

f = open("file123.html", 'w')
sys.stdout = f

f.close()
```

When I execute above code. I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bob\Documents\scripts\html\html.py", line 10, in <module>
    htmlcode = HTML.table(table_data)
AttributeError: type object 'HTML' has no attribute 'table'.
```

Is there any easiest way we can create table with color from python script

I am using python 2.7 in windows 10 OS.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the built-in html module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#module-html) with this third-party HTML module. Try starting with `import HTML` instead of `from html import HTML`.

Comment: Sir when i use import HTML i get no HTML module  error

Comment: How did you install the HTML module? Did you run `python setup.py install` as in the instructions? (also note that this module has apparently not been updated since 2009 - eww.)

Comment: Sir as you suspected, Installation not proper. I used pip install html. Now i downloaded and used python setup.py install in linux it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation of [HTML.py](https://www.decalage.info/python/html) states that tables are created like this: `t = HTML.Table(header_row=['Test', 'Result'])`
replace HTML.table with **HTML.Table** in your code (like below)

```
 import HTML
 import sys
 import os
 table_data = [
        ['Last name',   'First name',   'Age'],
        ['Smith',       'John',         30],
        ['Carpenter',   'Jack',         47],
        ['Johnson',     'Paul',         62],
    ]
htmlcode = HTML.Table(table_data)

f = open("file123.html", 'w')
sys.stdout = f

f.close()
```

make sure to also install the module correctly as described [here](https://github.com/decalage2/pyhtgen):

INSTALLATION:

- on Windows, double-click on install.bat, or type "setup.py install" in a CMD
  window.
- on other systems, type "python setup.py install" in a shell.

Comment: Sir, still same error. htmlcode = HTML.Table(table_data)
AttributeError: type object 'HTML' has no attribute 'Table'

Comment: where did you install the HTML module? When you import  from html import HTML you import the html module from the standard libary. Since you want to use this third party package you should run import HTML just as @Hugh Bothwell suggested (I updated the answer code)

Comment: Sir, As you stated installation not proper now working